# Cloudflare AWF Rate Limiting Rules: Add Rate limiting rules for subdomain

Tags: cloudflare, rate-limiting, websecurity

I am considering using **Cloudflare AWF Rate Limiting Rules** for my website. But before applying on my main domain **example.com**, I want to try it on my subdomain first **sub.example.com**

First step, I try to add a new site, it doesn’t support subdomain, root domain only [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rztdT.png)

Next step, add rate limiting rules:

1. With free plan account, it doesn’t support **URI full** on **Rate Limiting Rules**
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/634OM.png)
2. Acorrding to [Cloudflare docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/waf/rate-limiting-rules/#availability), **URI full** is only supported from **Pro plan** account up.

My question is, if I upgrade my account to Pro plan fully supports **URI full** is my subdomain **sub.example.com** then does **Rate Limiting Rules** only works on my **subdomain** or it effects entirely on my **root domain** as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL Full field with your subdomain, so that the rate limiting rule can only works for it.

[image]